# Cant fetch the data from JTable database to JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My `Jtable` is connected to the database that I made so that it can show all the data right in my GUI. But Im trying to fetch the data from my JTable to the JTextField. Its like when you click the row of the table the data from the database thats inside the table will go to the TextField. But when I clicked the table it shows an error like this:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NO.='1
>   RASCHEL" at line 1

I've been searching for the answer but I was unable to find one. Please help me I've been stuck to this error since friday.

```
table = new JTable();
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        String table_click = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where MACHINE NO.='" + table_click + "'";
            Connection con;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String machine = rs.getString("MACHINE NO.");
                String type = rs.getString("TYPE");
                String product = rs.getString("PRODUCT");
                txtMachine.setText(machine);
                txtType.setText(type);
                txtProd.setText(product);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould **not** use blanks and dots in column names. If you have to use blank and dot you have to escape the column name with a backtick:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where `MACHINE NO.`='"+table_click+"'";
```

But i would strongly recommand to not use blanks and dots  (or other special character) in column or table names.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where MACHINENO='"+table_click+"'";
```

Also change to prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Oh god. Thank you! This worked. Because of my frustration I didnt see that mistake. Thanks again for the answe. :)

Comment: I cant upvote because my reputation is 0. Im new here. :(

Answer (score 3):

The column you are using `MACHINE NO.` contains a space and a dot in the end to work with like names you have to put the name between two :

```
`MACHINE NO.`
```

So your query should look like this :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where `MACHINE NO.`='" + table_click + "'";
```

But this still not secure agains syntax error or SQL Injection so instead you can use :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where `MACHINE NO.` = ?";
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root","");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, table_click);//<<-----------set the parameter like this
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `raschel` where `MACHINE NO.`='"+table_click+"'";
```